# docker-machine with amazon ami HVM doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

When selecting the Amazon AMI `ami-606b6c60a` (HVM), `docker-machine` creates the AWS instance but it is in the "stopped" state.

If I switch to Amazon AMI `ami-5fb8c835` (PV), it works as expected.

```
$ docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-ami=ami-60b6c60a \
--amazonec2-access-key=MyKey --amazonec2-secret-key=MySecret \
--amazonec2-security-group=vpc-wide-open-for-testing-only \
--amazonec2-root-size=8 test
```

Extra info:

```
$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.5.0 (04cfa58)
```